# Rely on data member initialization to happen

Tags: c++

Suppose a class `D` maintaining a vector of objects of class `C`, and suppose that the first three elements of the vector shall be accessible through data members `field0 .. field2`, which are references to objects of class `C`.

If we initialise data members `field0 .. field2` at the point of their declaration, and none of the constructors of `D` uses explicit mem-initializer lists, is it guaranteed that the data members will always be initialised with a correct reference to the objects held in the vector (if we consider subclassing, copying, moving, ... an object of class `D`)?

Note that the question is not about the order of initialization but more on "can anything in the use of class D (including subclassing) prevent the data members from being initialised"?

```
class C{
};

class D{
protected:
    std::vector<C> myC = std::vector<C>(3);
public:
    C &field0 = myC[0];
    C &field1 = myC[1];
    C &field2 = myC[2];

    D () {};  // no mem-initializers
};
```

Comment: Actually it's not about the order of initialization but more on "can anything in the use of class `D` (including subclassing) prevent the data members from being initialised?

Comment: I'm not sure about initialization, but I'd gladly brick your implementation by resizing the vector in a subclass until it allocates a new memory area.